# Why is this POST variable sent via AJAX Null? (jquery/php)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This javascript is for a "load more" functionality. That grabs a fixed number of elements from load.php when a button #moreg is clicked.

```
$(function(){
    $("#moreg").click(load);
    var countg = -1;
    load();


    function load() {
        var num = 1;
        countg += num;
        $.post( "load.php", 
                {'start_g': 'countg', 'name':'<?=$name?>' }, 
                function(data){
                    $("#posts").append(data);
                }
        );
    }
});
```

in load.php simply doing a `var_dump($_POST['start_g']);`
yields a null variable.

Not too helpful...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example should work, var_dump should return the string 'count_g'. Try clearing the cache.

Comment: What do you see when you do a `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @James Allardice: Undelete your answer, the quotes on the *value* were the problem, the quotes on the *keys* was just a side issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the map of parameters that get sent with the POST request, the keys do not have to be quoted (but it doesn't make any difference):

```
$.post("load.php", {
    start_g: countg, 
    name: '<?=$name?>' 
}, function(data) {
    $("#posts").append(data);
});
```

And I've also removed the quotes from `countg`, because you're trying to use the value of a variable. If it's quoted, you're simply going to pass the string "countg" rather than the value of the variable named `countg`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was just about to edit. In fact, in some cases, quotes are required (I don't think the underscore is one of those cases though). *In fact* that means my answer is completely wrong... `$_POST["start_g"]` should contain "countg", and definitely should not be `null`. Deleting...

Comment: yeah not sure why it was returning null...but removing the quotes around it fixed the problem...odd..i must have had something else that was wrong that got fixed.